# jQuery 3.5.1 callback function in .animate() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a problem making a callback function in `.animate()`.
The animation goes very smoothly and without problems, but the `complete: ()=>` part is not working at all. I've copied this structure from the documentation but it just doesn't want to coop after my changes. Does anyone know why it doesn't work? Is it cause by setInterval? If so, how can I loop this animation?

The code is as follows:

```
setInterval(() => {
    $(".slide")[0].animate({
        "marginLeft": "-100%"
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: "linear",
        complete: () => {
            console.log("test");
        },
    });
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I suspect that it's related to `$(".slide")[0]`, this would return an element and not a jQuery Object. Try `$(".slide")` or `$(".slide").eq(0)` if you have multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks Twisty! Changing `$(".slide")[0]` to `$(".slide").eq(0)` worked! You're a legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make use of the correct selector:

```
setInterval(() => {
    $(".slide").eq(0).animate({
        "marginLeft": "-100%"
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: "linear",
        complete: () => {
            console.log("test");
        },
    });
}, 6000);
```

When you get element `0` fro mthe Object, it returns the DOM Element and not a jQuery Object. See More:

https://api.jquery.com/eq/